# SimpleDateFormat bug with Large Dates

Tags: android, simpledateformat

*update: I thought the Android version was to blame, but it turns out it is the user-timezone*

This code produces incorrect output when my tablets time is in Central European time (+2 in summer time):

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.GERMAN);

        Date testDate = dateTimeFormatter
                .parse("2999-01-01 00:00:00 +0100");
        Log.v(TAG, "test 1 " + testDate);

        testDate = dateTimeFormatter.parse("2099-01-01 00:00:00 +0100");
        Log.v(TAG, "test 2 " + testDate);
```

"test 1 Mon Dec 31 23:19:32 CET 2998"

"test 2 Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2099"

There is a time difference. Why the 40 minutes and some seconds difference on the larger date?

The bug is not present when I put my tablet in (most) other timezones. Something to do with timezones that have dailight saving hours?

Comment: I had that some problem with daylight savings, it is a java related issue if you want to research on that subject you can look for a solution made for java if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I cannot overcome this bug, I've built my own date parser.

*Update: my own parser has the same problem*

My current solution is just not using these large dates. If date > 100 years in future, I set it to 100 years in the future.